# What cause the performance variation of multithread Java program on Android system?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dalvik, tegra

I tried to run a multithread Java program (in MapReduce style) on Google Nexus 7, and measured the execution time with

```
System.currentMillis();
```

I found that the performance varies a lot (w/ 4 threads on Tegra 3 w/ 4 cores), as below:

`704 
872 
729 
729 
1086 
778 
1214 
1045 
749 
768`

However, when I used the sequential version, I got stable data like this:

`928 
851 
850 
842 
863 
917 
873 
905 
853 
870`

I thought the garbage collector is concurrent so it also takes a core, is it the reason cause the big variations?

Why sometimes the performance is even much worse than the sequential version?

Comment: It really depends on how efficient the threads are... Without knowing that, it's hard to say. But in general, you don't want to have too many threads.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought the garbage collector is also multithreaded, is it the reason cause the big variations?

IMO, it is unlikely that the GC is the cause of the variability.

> Why sometimes the performance is even much worse than the sequential version?

We would need to look at your code or an SSCE.  However, my guess the reasons are that:

- this is a problem which is a poor fit for the performance characteristics of Java threading (e.g. the high cost of creating threads), or
- your multi-threaded solution has a significant concurrency bottleneck and or load balance.

Comment: If it is caused by your guessed reasons, the performance would always be worse. However, most times, it is noticeably better.

Comment: @JackWM - *"the performance would always be worse"* - Not necessarily.  Thread scheduling effects can often cause a bottleneck etc to manifest *in a non-deterministic way*.  Anyway, the bottom line is that we can't give you a real explanation without seeing your code ... or better still an SSCE.